# Как вернуть незакомиченные данные?

Tags: git

Сделала изменения в проекте. Хотела закомитить. Выдало ошибку. Сделала revert. Слетело все, что сделала сегодня. Можно вернуть изменения, если нету коммита?

Comment: Можно вернуть изменения, если нету коммита? - если буквально то да (пишите кодик ручками во второй раз). А если нет то и мне интересно

Comment: @AzizUmarov прав, если нет коммита - то доставать изменения неоткуда. Еще бы хотелось знать что имеется в виду под `revert` ибо изначально реверт делает коммит, отменяющий предыдущий коммит.

Comment: Как делали `revert`? С помощью `git revert`? Или из IDE? Если из IDE, то укажите какой IDE пользуетесь, т.к. эти операции могут называться по разному и `revert` в IDE может на самом деле выполнять `git reset`. Если делали из командной строки, то укажите команду которой пользовались. Сейчас в вопросе недостаточно информации чтобы ответить однозначно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избежать `git revert`, используйте `git stash`. Эта команда визуально отменяет незакомиченные изменения в коде, но на самом деле они сохраняет них в своём стеке. Чтобы их вернуть, добавьте к последней команде слово `pop`

```
git stash pop
```